# How can I specify the memory allocation for Cloud Functions when deploying a Next.js web app with Firebase?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-tools

I was able to deploy a web app created with Next.js on Firebase, but when I try to interact with it, I encounter the following error, and the program exits prematurely:
**Memory limit of 256 MiB exceeded with 260 MiB used. Consider increasing the memory limit, see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory**

Even though I increased the memory allocation to 512MiB from the Google Cloud Console and redeployed Cloud Functions, the console shows that it's changed to 512MiB, but I still get the same error when interacting with the app, indicating that the changes haven't taken effect. When I attempt to reflect the changes by redeploying from my local environment using `firebase deploy`, the memory allocation reverts to the initial value of 256MiB. How can I deploy with a memory allocation of 512MiB?

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this same issue and was able to resolve it by specifying the amount of memory to allocate for the Next.js SSR function by editing the `frameworksBackend` section of the `firebase.json` file in the root of my project.

```
{
  "functions": [
    {
      "runtime": "nodejs18",
      "source": "functions",
      "codebase": "default",
      "ignore": [
        "node_modules",
        ".git",
        "firebase-debug.log",
        "firebase-debug.*.log"
      ],
      "predeploy": [
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
        "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "hosting": {
    "source": ".",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "frameworksBackend": {
      "region": "us-central1",
      "memory": "512MiB"
    }
  }
}
```

The options able to be used in the `frameworksBackend` section are the same as for any 2nd gen Cloud Function. The complete list is available at  [firebase-functions/v2/https.httpsOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.https.httpsoptions).

More documentation can be viewed at [Firebase CLI & Web Frameworks](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-framework-tools/blob/main/README.md).

Comment: This is exactly the method I was looking for! When I actually tried it, it worked well. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Every time you deploy a function with the Firebase CLI, it will reset all of the function configurations.  That's how your memory setting keeps changing.  If you want the same value every time you deploy, you should specify that value in the code of your function instead of modifying it in the console.

There is [documentation on how to change your function memory settings](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have read the documentation, but there are still some parts I don't understand.

Comment: When deploying a Next.js application, Firebase automatically generates the code for Cloud Functions and creates a single function. The code is placed in the `.firebase/[PROJECT_NAME]/functions/server.js` file like this:
``exports.[FUNCTION_NAME]=onRequest({ region: [REGION] },(req, res) => server.then((it) => it.handle(req, res))
);``
I thought that changing it to onRequest({memory: "512MiB"}, (req, res)=>{}) would work, but editing this file directly is ineffective because it gets overwritten during the firebase deploy process. Where should I make the changes for it to work correctly?

Comment: If you have a new question, please post it separately.  You should be editing *YOUR* code, not anything that was generated under the .firebase directory.  Your new question should show your code and explain what you intend to do with it, or what isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: I will do as you suggested. Thank you for your guidance.

Answer (score 1):

If you change memory allocation on console you don't need to redeploy functions because deployed code will already be running with new allocation you set.

You can also set function memory allocation directly inside your code:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions'

....

exports.myFunction = functions
  .runWith( {
    // '128MB', '256MB', '512MB', etc....
    memory: '1GB'
  } )
  .https.onRequest( () => { ... } )
```

Now every time you deploy your function it will update memory allocation automatically so you doesn't need to update it on console.

You can also read more about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions?gen=2nd&hl=pt-br#set_timeout_and_memory_allocation).

Comment: I thought I was getting the same error even after making changes from the console, but it seems I was mistaken, as the changes were indeed reflected, as you mentioned. I believe there is a different issue than what I expected. I appreciate you including the memory allocation code. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions/v2'

export const yourfunctioname = 
functions.https.onRequest({'cpu': 2, memory: "1GiB"},(request,response)=>{...})
```

> note that cpu 2 may not work for u u need to updae concurrency or make cpu 1